# How can I involve middleware in my chat bot when I'm using Mvc() in Configure. Am I need to create a extension method for it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, botframework, adapter, middleware

I would like to add two middlewares to my chat bot, one for processing some custom parameters , another for logger. 
In my startup.cs, Configure method, i use app.UseMvc() instead of app.UseBotFramework().
How can i involve middlewares when I'm using mvc.

> ```
>   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
>     {
>         if (env.IsDevelopment())
>         {
>             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             app.UseHsts();
>         }
>         app.UseDefaultFiles();
>         app.UseStaticFiles();
>         //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
>         //app.UseBotFramework();
>         app.UseMvc();
>     }
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

We can add the middleware in controller, sample code as below.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task PostAsync()
{
  // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
  // The adapter will invoke the bot.
  ((BotAdapter)_adapter).Use(new EndpointMiddleware());
  await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);
}
```

Not sure is this the right way to do it, but it working properly..